# Using "spring-boot-starter-webflux" and "spring-boot-starter-web" together

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use `WebClient` instead of `RestTemplate` in my spring boot MVC Application, yet I couldn't find a specific dependency only for the `WebClient`, My application is fully MVC and as explained in [the Spring Boot reference documentation section about WebFlux, adding both web and webflux starters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux) will configure a Spring MVC web application, But that's not the case, When I added both I received the below error

```
2019-06-14 09:10:13.196  WARN 69495 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:

The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled, e.g. via @EnableWebMvc and @EnableWebFlux, in the same application.
```

Note That I'm neither using `@EnableWebMvc` nor `@EnableWebFlux` on any of the Config classes.

Here's my Pom

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

Comment: The fact that you are getting error from the initialization of the bean `WebFluxAutoConfiguration`, means that the webflux is enabled somehow, I investigated but couldn't find a way for it to be enabled other than having the `@EnableWebFlux`... Maybe through some dependencies you are getting some beans that enable the webflux?

Comment: Can you try to enforce MVC via `SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)` ?

Comment: I didn't use webflux dependency before, I only added it to get the webclient, so there shouldn't be "in theory" any dependency that enables webflux, and I've tried to set the webapplication type but it didn't work and I think it make sense, cause the main issue is about the unwanted enablement of `@EnableWebFlux`

Comment: It doen't make sense to use web and webflux together and the error message is clear: The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled

Comment: When using Spring Boot and its auto configuration, WebFlux and WebMvc are both enabled automatically. As @SimonMartinelli said, using them together won't work.

Comment: It does work, please read the documentation and the links I've provided in the post, I've fixed it, I'll post the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the provided link, in [the Spring Boot reference documentation section about WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux), adding both web and webflux starters should work if you want to Use the webclient in an mvc servlets environment, I just had to clean my IDE cache and that was the issue.
As a note: if you wanna start your environment programmatically you can choose one of the standard spring provided environments as below

```
//For Reactive
ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardReactiveWebEnvironment();
//For Servlets mvc environment
ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardServletEnvironment();
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the spring documentation here [Web Application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-web-environment)

> A SpringApplication attempts to create the right type of `ApplicationContext` on your behalf. The algorithm used to determine a `WebApplicationType` is fairly simple:
>
> If Spring MVC is present, an `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` is used
>
> If Spring MVC is not present and Spring WebFlux is present, an `AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext` is used
>
> Otherwise, `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is used
>
> This means that if you are using Spring MVC and the new `WebClient` from Spring  WebFlux in the same application, Spring MVC will be used by default. You can override that easily by calling `setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType)`.
>
> It is also possible to take complete control of the `ApplicationContext` type that is used by calling `setApplicationContextClass(…​)`.

Says that if Spring MVC and Webflux is on the class path, Spring MVC will be preferred. This behaviour can be overridden.

This might give you some tips to start where to debug or try as suggested to force the application to be a servlet application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
    application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.SERVLET);
    application.run(args);
}
```